# CMakeインストール

Tags: python, linux, pip, cmake

cmakeをLINUXにインストールしようとしたところERRORがでました。

```
pip install  --user cmake-3.18.4.post1.tar.gz
Processing ./cmake-3.18.4.post1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command /home/devadmin/anaconda3/bin/python /home/devadmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-9txe6o3t/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- scikit-build setuptools wheel:
```

Comment: 恐らく [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/338733) でも同じ質問をしており、"cmake は Python のライブラリではないから pip でインストールできない" という回答もついており、本人も納得されているように見えます。

Comment: Linuxの各種ディストリビューションでは, (大抵)それぞれにパッケージマネージャーがあるので, 何の Linux使ってるかがわかればそれに応じた cmakeのインストール方法がわかるはずです。(質問に追記してみてください)

Answer (score 0):

cmakeはPythonのライブラリではないので、pipではインストール出来ないと思います。

https://qiita.com/wasnot/items/76ecc844723965c7d433

このリンクでやってみてはいかがですか。

Answer (score 0):

先の回答者の方もおしゃられているように、cmakeをpipではインストールできないようです。
LINUXにcmakeをインストールする方法として下記のような方法があるようですので、参考になればと思います。

https://qiita.com/pollenjp/items/391afc3e9f93006b83ba